# Eliminar item de uma variavel que contém uma lista

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um programa maior, mas o meu problema está a residir na eliminação de um item de uma variavel que contém uma lista lá dentro e por isso criei este [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umd8px2r/) só com a parte do meu erro.

Coloquei 2 `alert()` para conseguir perceber se a função é executada ou não.

```
var listaHTML = '<li id=\"liItem1\"  class=\"listItem\">item1</li>'
                    + '<li id=\"liItem2\"  class=\"listItem\">item2</li>'
                    + '<li id=\"liItem3\"  class=\"listItem\">item3</li>'
                    + '<li id=\"liItem4\"  class=\"listItem\">item4</li>'
                    + '<li id=\"liItem5\"  class=\"listItem\">item5</li>'
                    + '<li id=\"liItem6\"  class=\"listItem\">item6</li>'
                    + '<li id=\"liItem7\"  class=\"listItem\">item7</li>'
                    + '<li id=\"liItem8\"  class=\"listItem\">item8</li>'
                    + '<li id=\"liItem9\"  class=\"listItem\">item9</li>'
                    + '<li id=\"liItem10\" class=\"listItem\">item10</li>';

alert(listaHTML);


$("#liItem5").remove();

alert(listaHTML);
```

Como podem ver, o 2ª alerto continua igual ao 1º, mas estava a tentar fazer com que, neste caso, o `li` com o `id=liItem5` fosse removido da variavel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro criares uma `div` onde colocas esse HTML e removeres esse `li` por essa via. Dessa maneira o HTML é interpretado pelo Browser e o jQuery consegue encontrar o elemento que queres. Assim:

```
var div = $('<div/>');
var listaHTML = '<li id=\"liItem1\"  class=\"listItem\">item1</li>'
                    + '<li id=\"liItem2\"  class=\"listItem\">item2</li>'
                    + '<li id=\"liItem3\"  class=\"listItem\">item3</li>'
                    + '<li id=\"liItem4\"  class=\"listItem\">item4</li>'
                    + '<li id=\"liItem5\"  class=\"listItem\">item5</li>'
                    + '<li id=\"liItem6\"  class=\"listItem\">item6</li>'
                    + '<li id=\"liItem7\"  class=\"listItem\">item7</li>'
                    + '<li id=\"liItem8\"  class=\"listItem\">item8</li>'
                    + '<li id=\"liItem9\"  class=\"listItem\">item9</li>'
                    + '<li id=\"liItem10\" class=\"listItem\">item10</li>';
div.html(listaHTML);
div.find("#liItem5").remove();
alert(div.html());
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/umd8px2r/1/

O problema que tinhas é que quando usas `$("#liItem5")` estás à procura no DOM por um elemento com esse ID. E ele não existe no DOM, somente numa string dentro da tua variável.